# Функция меняющая цвета js

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, функции

Требуется создать функцию при исполнении которой, все элементы в html/css коде цвета #FAFAFA, меняли цвет на #333.

Comment: Перебрать подключенные стили, поменять там значения, а потом для всех элементов страницы проверить inline-значения. Либо просто для всех элементов страницы через getComputedStyle, а потом их как-то перекрасить.

Comment: Нужна реализация в виде кода, я пока слаб в js.

Comment: @RuslanBayramov, а зачем это вообще понадобилось, и почему просто в css не поменять ?

Comment: Хочется чтобы на любой странице сайта присутствовала кнопка, которая меняет тему.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример с "просто изменение цвета". Попробуйте доработать его сами.

А вообще, менять цвет элемента из js вот таким перебором, это одна из самых ужасных практик. Попробуйте организовать элементы в группы с помощью аттрибута class и меняйте добавляя/удаляя требуемый класс у элемента

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  let els = $('body').find('*')
  els.each((i, el) => {
   el.style.background = '#ddd'
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам наглядный пример как это делается!

Можете изменить цвет фона **при клике при hover даже можете написать имя цвета** которое вам нужно в `input` чтобы получить его тут нет ничего сложного.

```js
change_background = (color) => {document.bgColor = color;}
```

```html
<form> 
  <label>цвет: <input type="text" name="color" > 
  </label>
  <input name="clrs" type ="button" value="взять цвет" onClick = "change_background(color.value) " > 
</form>
<a href="#" onClick="change_background('#099')">Голубой цвет</a>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="change_background('#111')">Черный цвет</a>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="change_background('#333')">Ваш цвет #333</a>
```

Comment: Во-первых, `bgColor` устарел сто лет назад, во-вторых, ответ с вопросом вообще не связан.

Comment: @Qwertiy   =( почему не связан я показал как менять цвета

Comment: Цвет фона изменять не надо, надо изменять цвета всех элементов, которые имеют определенный цвет

Answer (score 1):

```js
const hexToRgb = hex => {
  let arrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(4);
  let vw = new DataView(arrBuff);
  vw.setUint32(0, parseInt(hex, 16), false);
  let arrByte = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);
  return arrByte[1] + ", " + arrByte[2] + ", " + arrByte[3];
}

const color = new RegExp(hexToRgb("FAFAFA"), "gi");

const newColor = hexToRgb("333333");

const replacement = cssText => {
  return cssText.match(color) && cssText.replace(color, newColor);
}

const sheets = document.styleSheets;

for (let len = sheets.length, si = 0; si < len; si++) {
  let rules = sheets[si].cssRules;
  if (!rules) {
    continue
  }
  for (let len = rules.length, ri = 0; ri < len; ri++) {
    let cssText = rules[ri].cssText;
    cssText = replacement(cssText);
    if (!cssText) {
      continue
    }
    document.styleSheets[si].insertRule(cssText, rules.length);
    document.styleSheets[si].deleteRule(ri);
  }
}

const styled = document.querySelectorAll("[style]");

[].forEach.call(styled, element => {
  let cssText = replacement(element.style.cssText);
  if (cssText) {
    element.style.cssText = cssText
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.test {
  background: #FAFAFA;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: #FAFAFA"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```